# I can't find any way to install requests or lxml, i'm using python 3.6.0 and i have a windows computer with a 64 bit OP system

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

So, I started with LXML, but I couldn't get it to work, from [this website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) 
the first one. (lxml-4.3.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl)

So, so far I have tried:

```
pip install lxml-4.3.4-cp27-cp27m-win32
```

and got the below error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
   pip install lxml-4.3.4-cp27-cp27m-win32
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get the same problem no matter what I look up.
Same thing with requests.

Comment: pip is a command you run from the command line, not from python. And you just use the package name: `pip install requests`.

Comment: In addition to that, you might need to supply the full path to *pip*. As a note both packages are built on *PyPI*, so no need to download the custom versions. Also *Python 2.7* has only 6.3 months to live.

Comment: @DanielRoseman true, altough some IDEs allow pip to be run in python consoles. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip is used in the command line, so in your case Command Prompt. This command will most likely work, however you seem to be inputting it into the wrong place: the Python shell rather than the Command Prompt.

Depending on how your PATH variable is set up, you may have to use:

```
python -m pip install [name of program trying to install]
```

Comment: You will need to add Python to your PATH. Easiest way of doing this is by uninstalling and installing Python again and making sure the "Add to PATH" option is ticked at the end of the installation